# Android Studio not giving option for adding new activity

Tags: android, svn, android-activity, android-studio

I am using a Project from a Subversion repository. I want to add a new activity in my project. when I am go to "new" for add new activity I found just five Options mention below :

```
file  
Directory  
C++ Class  
C/C++ Source File  
C/C++ Header File
```

Normally in this menu, there should be all the Android specific activities, widgets and so on but i am getting this options only.Please check the attached screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone face similar issue or knows what is the issue? I am using Android SDK API 18-Android 4.3.API 17 and API 23 are also installed.

Comment: File -> Project Structure -> check if under Modules there is something (like app folder)

Comment: Looks like you might have a gradle error. Try to build the project and see if any errors show in the Messages panel.

Answer (score 1):

Your project is not recognized as a Android project by AndroidStudio. Have you just imported it from a local src?

From your screenshot, I find your project is not a gradle project. I highly recommend you to manage your Android project using gradle. After you finish your gradle setting, run “gradle build -debug” in your project root path, you will get more information.